# No diff_drive_controller for ARM?

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, beaglebone, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi - I have a differential drive robot based on the BeagleBone Black (it's actually the robot built for a Coursera course). I'd really like to use the diff_drive_controller, but there isn't a debian package in the ARM repo. The BBB has Ubuntu 13.04 and ROS Hydro on it.

Any idea why that specific package is absent from the ARM repo?

I did try to build diff_drive_controller myself on the BBB but ran into other problems. I'd rather stick with official binaries though, if possible.

Also - I tried to include links to a lot of the items mentioned above but I don't have enough karma - sorry for that. :(

Thanks,
Zach

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172497/no-diff_drive_controller-for-arm?/) by [zcox](https://answers.ros.org/users/18031/zcox/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2014-06-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the diff_drive_controller package didn't exist when I did the last set of ARM builds for Hydro.

You can probably build it from source if you use the latest hydro-devel branches of the ros_control and ros_controllers repositories.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0